# Swap procedure not working in MIPS

Tags: mips, procedure

The objective of this program is to swap two numbers without using temporary variables. I came up with a solution by just using math but when I assemble, the numbers don't swap and I can't figure out why. Can anyone explain my mistake?

```
.text
main:
la  $a0,n1
la  $a1,n2
jal swap
li  $v0,1   # print n1 and n2; should be 27 and 14
lw  $a0,n1
syscall
li  $v0,11
li  $a0,' '
syscall
li  $v0,1
lw  $a0,n2
syscall
li  $v0,11
li  $a0,'\n'
syscall
li  $v0,10  # exit
syscall

swap:    #this is my code and where I'm having problems
sub $a0, $a0, $a1
add $a1, $a1, $a0
sub $a0, $a1, $a0
jr $ra

.data
n1: .word 14
n2: .word 27
```

Comment: `la  $a0,n1` loads the _address_ of `n1` into `$a0`. So you're swapping addresses, which has no effect on the values located at those addresses (i.e. `lw $a0,n1` will give you the same value as before the swap).

Comment: @Michael So would I have to use `lw $a0, n1` within the swap procedure to be able to swap the words?

Comment: Load the values, swap them, write them back (or print them).